# C++: How to start an array in a class?

Tags: c++, arrays, oop

I've been trying to learn C++ by creating a text-based game. In this game I create a MapHandler, which has a grid (multidimensional array, 5x5, int). I want to be able to pass the class a grid when it's called, but I can't seem to be able to do it.

My question is: How do I  set a value -from outside- for an array in a class?

I have wrote some code that replicates my mistake:

```
// ConsoleApplication2.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Person {
    public:
        int age;
        string characteristics[5];
        Person();
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string traits[5] = {'Stubborn','Ambitious','Smart','Emotional','Extrovert'};
    Person Bob;

    Bob.age = 18;
    Bob.characteristics = traits;

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I've been trying to learn C++ by creating a text-based game." - try doing it reading an introductory book.

Comment: Use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

Comment: string should quoted by double quote not single quote: `'Stubborn'`

Comment: You should start off correctly and use `std::vector` and not arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not able to copy the raw array (i.e. `int a[5], b[5]; b=a;`). You will have to copy them element by element:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    Bob.characteristics[i] = traits[i];
```

or even better:

```
#include <algorithm>


// ...

std::copy(traits, traits+5, Bob.characteristics);
```

Answer (score 4):

In c++, plain arrays are not first class, ie they cannot be copied. You'd benefit by using a [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead.